# How do I add a target="_blank" attribute to Footer Menu Block Link in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-blocks, drupal-menu

Is there any way to add blank attribute if i created a Footer Menu Block with Links in Drupal 7 ?

Attached see my options so far...
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try: https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes for d7.. You would get attributes for each menu link.